# ul padding not applying next to a floating img

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, html-lists

I have a very basic CSS problem.

I have a floating image in my top-left corner with a `margin-right`. The content is made of paragraphs and lists with bullets. I want my lists to have a `padding-left` for more visibility and my bullets appear in "`list-style-position: outside`" (text must be aligned).

My problem is, when a list is displayed next to my floating image, ul padding is not applying.

Here is an annotated screenshot for your comprehension :

[image]

This kind of behavior happens with FF and Chrome. With IE, it is worse because the bullets appear at the very left of the floating image...

Edit : css property "`ul{overflow: hidden;}`" is not an option because I want to avoid this :

[image]

I'm sorry I can't show you a piece of code because it is a Drupal website and the content of the node is generated by wysiwyg module and written by webmaster and editors. I have no access to the generated structure. The content is not fixed and lists could appear everywhere in the text.

**This Fiddle represents well my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/34Cuf/**

Comment: did you try to clear your floats?

Comment: @DD0UG Div containing floating img is clear:both

Comment: Post your full code, and create jsfiddle or give us link to your page so we can work on this.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I'm afraid I can't because this project is too huge, there are many sass files, and HTML is displayed by Drupal templates... I wrote down css properties related to elements that cause the issue. Here is a link where the problem appears online: http://www.infos-entreprises.be/fr/couts-de-creation-13

Comment: just clear floats after image. add this after div with .Image-left class <div style="clear: both;"></div>

Comment: There already is a cleardiv after my image @MiljanPuzović

Comment: No there isn't. You cannot set float and clear float in the same element (you can but there is no point). Remove float and set width of image to 100%, or left that float there and clear float right before ul list.

Comment: When I add the cleardiv where you suggest to add it, it is all my text content that is sent below the image.

`<?php
  if (isset($node->field_image_template['und']['0']['value'])) {
    $image_template = $node->field_image_template['und']['0']['value'];
  }
  else {
    $image_template = 'Image-left';
  }
  print '<div class="' . $image_template . '">';
  print render($content['field_media_image']);
  print '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>';
  ?>` aaaand screenshot ;-) http://awesomescreenshot.com/0152nh3h57

Comment: I know, it's better to do it that way. Now put larger image. Or, you can put clardiv after that bolder text "Independamment de la procedure..."

Comment: Sorry but your answer is rather an alternative than a solution ^^ I do not decide of the design, this is not my job ;-) I have to process as I said, with a small image floating!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to get rid of this:

```
list-style-position: outside
```

This is putting your bullets points outside of padding. In the box model, anything outside the border box collapses during a float.

Comment: I'm afraid that even when this property is deleted, or when it is modified to "list-style-position:inside", it doesn't apply the padding anyway. I tried before and re-check again now for you. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0222ngoc15

Answer (score 1):

Lists have initial left padding on them (so there is enough space to show the bullet) so unless you give the `ul` a padding that is greater than this initial value, your list will actually move left instead of right.

[Have a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/LyY8B/2/)

To make your ul behave properly next to a floated element you just need to float it too: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LyY8B/5/)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow you. If I delete the margin-right of my floating image, I don't see the bullets anymore (because of list-style-position: outside). See what I mean here : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ca2ngs5d3

Plus, wrapping all my ul in a div is not an option because this content is generated by a wysiwyg.

Comment: They disappear behind your floated element - see this: http://jsfiddle.net/LyY8B/4/ so you just need to add a margin right that is greater than the ul's natural left padding (around 35px) - have a look at my updated answer

Comment: And that is exactly what I did. I just want my lists to be "more indented" than my paragraphs, even next to floating img.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your edit. Make my lists float couldn't work because they are everywhere in the content, between paragraphs. If I do so, the text won't make sense anymore. Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0762ngxz62

Comment: is you ul next to the image in the html? if so you could use something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LyY8B/6/)

Comment: As I said, this content (different on each page) is generated by a wysiwyg and is not fixed and definitive (webmaster and editors can change the content of the website). Therefore I can't predict where the lists are going to be written in the text. I can't base on your example :-(

Comment: @Pete Here is link to site http://www.infos-entreprises.be/fr/couts-de-creation-13

Comment: Ah if it is content editable, there's not much you can really do that won't effect all uls in the area.  The images look small enough that your intro paragraph will usually take up most of it.  I would just force the ul to start on a new line with a clear left so it's padding works properly

Comment: I've suggested the same.

Answer (score 0):

Padding won't apply to list at right of floating div, because it stays behind floating div.
It doesn't count from after div, it still counting from left as `ul` after floating div.
It happens because the div "floats" with text.

To understand it better, play it `ul li` padding in my example [**in fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/andretf/tL7hm/)

See that a put a little margin in floating div to you see that the content of ul extends form the left margin behind floating div.

You'll have to apply a bigger right margin to the floating div.

Comment: I already thought about that solution. But what about paragraphs I don't want to be indented?

Comment: apply negative padding to other paragraphs, and positive to `ul` until find right point between them.

Comment: What about paragraphs that are not next to the floating img? They're going to get the negative padding too! Aren't they?